# running parallel stored procedures using php

Tags: php, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

I'm looking for a reliable way of sending and controlling parallel stored procedures using php.

I want to call many stored procedures at the same time and controlling their results.

For example, I want to call `p1`, `p2`,..`p10`, and to run `p1` and `p2` in parallel and if `p1` or `p2` has no result call `p3` - `p10` to run in parallel, and wait until all of them finished their process.

I read that "exec" can work in the background, but I didn't find an example of using exec to call a stored procedures and managing them.

Is there an example or a way I can implement that?

Thank you

Comment: Stored procedures of a database? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You can try `fork()`, but it will not give you ability to trace results in other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, but I already read that exec is probably the best way to do that, but I didn't understood if I can implement that with stored procedures.

I'm using a mysql DB and I perform an AJAX call to a PHP file that call stored procedure in the database.